# Importing data in CakePHP

Tags: database, cakephp

I took a certain system of relations in my database and when I started write models I came to some problem. First maybe I'll show my database schema.

```
##USERS##
id

##CVS##
id
user_id

##SKILLS##
id
cv_id

user hasOne cv
cv belongsTo user
cv hasMany skill
skill belongsTo cv
```

This solution seemed to be correct, but when I tried to get cv_id in skills table then I had to write something like this:

```
$cv_id = $this->Skill->find('first', array('user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')));
$this->request->data['Skill']['cv_id'] = $cv_id['CV']['id'];
```

I find it very messy solution. Is there any better way to get this information in cakePHP or maybe I should change my relations between tables? What should I do in this case?

Comment: What is the messy thing here. Kindly explain how you actually want to get the cv_id. So that you can get some answers.

Comment: I wanted to know how do it better, because in my opinion it's not the best way. I use CakePHP until two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
$this->Skill->virtualFields['cvid'] = 'CV.id';
$cv_id = $this->Skill->find('first', array('user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')));
$this->request->data['Skill']['cv_id'] = $cv_id['Skill']['cvid'];

---------------------- OR -----------------------------

$this->Skill->virtualFields['cv_title'] = 'CV.title';
$cv_id = $this->Skill->find('first', array('user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')));
$this->request->data['Skill']['cv_title'] = $cv_id['Skill']['cv_title'];

---------------------- OR -----------------------------

$this->Skill->virtualFields['cv_title'] = 'CV.title';
$this->request->data = $this->Skill->find('first', array('user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')));
```

You can dynamically add virtualFields using above syntax.

Here is the [explaination](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#limitations-of-virtualfields).
Hope it will work for you.